# Python: what does await do in the following context?

Tags: python, async-await, coroutine

I try to learn coroutines from example located at https://github.com/ajdavis/coroutines-demo/blob/master/50.py. It was created by user https://stackoverflow.com/users/618967/a-jesse-jiryu-davis in 2015.

I see `await f` multiple times in the code. `f` was an empty Future, why it needs to be `await`. Can someone explain this concept in a more cleary way?

```
from selectors import DefaultSelector, EVENT_WRITE, EVENT_READ
import socket
import time

selector = DefaultSelector()
n_jobs = 0

class Future:
    def __init__(self):
        self.callback = None

    def resolve(self):
        self.callback()

    def __await__(self):
        yield self

class Task:
    def __init__(self, coro):
        self.coro = coro
        self.step()

    def step(self):
        try:
            f = self.coro.send(None)
        except StopIteration:
            return

        f.callback = self.step

async def get(path):
    global n_jobs
    n_jobs += 1
    s = socket.socket()
    s.setblocking(False)
    try:
        s.connect(('localhost', 5000))
    except BlockingIOError:
        pass

    f = Future()
    selector.register(s.fileno(), EVENT_WRITE, f)
    await f
    selector.unregister(s.fileno())

    s.send(('GET %s HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n' % path).encode())
    buf = []

    while True:
        f = Future()
        selector.register(s.fileno(), EVENT_READ, f)
        await f
        selector.unregister(s.fileno())
        chunk = s.recv(1000)
        if chunk:
            buf.append(chunk)
        else:
            break

    # Finished.
    print((b''.join(buf)).decode().split('\n')[0])
    n_jobs -= 1

start = time.time()
Task(get('/foo'))
Task(get('/bar'))

while n_jobs:
    events = selector.select()
    for key, mask in events:
        future = key.data
        future.resolve()

print('took %.2f seconds' % (time.time() - start))
```

Comment: @a-jesse-jiryu-davis Any comment from the original author?

Comment: Stack Overflow doesn't let you ping arbitrary users like that. They have to have already interacted with the post you're commenting on in [one of a few specific ways](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work).

Comment: [Source](https://github.com/ajdavis/coroutines-demo/blob/master/50.py),  [Context](https://github.com/aosabook/500lines/blob/master/crawler/crawler.markdown)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is a kind of weird way to use `await`. Most code that uses `await` doesn't interact with the coroutine implementation as directly as this code does.

---

Python coroutines are implemented on top of the old iterator and generator machinery, with a little extra enforcement to avoid mixing them up. `get` works like a generator, and `await f` works like `yield from f.__await__()` would if `f` were a generator. Since `f.__await__` is implemented as `yield self`, `await f` behaves like `yield f`. (Don't try replacing `await f` with any sort of `yield` - manually `yield`ing doesn't work the same way in a coroutine.)

The code you're looking at wraps all `get` coroutines in a `Task` object, and `Task.step` looks like this:

```
def step(self):
    try:
        f = self.coro.send(None)
    except StopIteration:
        return

    f.callback = self.step
```

`f = self.coro.send(None)` advances the coroutine until it yields a Future, and assigns the Future to `f`. `f.callback = self.step` sets the future's callback, which will be called with `future.resolve()` later.

`get` calls `selector.register(s.fileno(), EVENT_READ, f)`. This registers the specified file with the selector, so when the file becomes ready for reading, the output of `selector.select()` will include a `SelectorKey` indicating this fact. Any object passed as the third `register` argument will be attached to the `SelectorKey`, so here, the Future will be attached to the `SelectorKey`.

In the following loop:

```
while n_jobs:
    events = selector.select()
    for key, mask in events:
        future = key.data
        future.resolve()
```

`events = selector.select()` waits for any of the registered files to be available for reading. `future = key.data` extracts the associated Future from the `SelectorKey`, and `future.resolve()` calls `Task.step`, which advances the associated coroutine until it yields again or terminates.